# Microsoft Edge: How to handle placeholder with text-align bug

Tags: css, input, microsoft-edge, placeholder, text-align

There is a bug in Edge where empty input fields with a placeholder attribute ignore the text-align property.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4468563/

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1743283/microsoft-edge-placeholder-with-text-align-right-bug

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z4fkev4v/

```
<h3>text-align: right</h3>
<input class="right" type="text" />
<input class="right" type="text" placeholder="wrong cursor alignment" />

.right {
text-align: right;
}
```

Is there any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me on Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0

Comment: the placeholder is aligned correctly but the cursor remains on the left side

Comment: yes I understand... the cursor was on the right side for me in Edge

Comment: strange..same version like you..

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to remove the placeholder on focus:

```
   $(function () {
        $("#TextBox1").focusin(function () {
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
        });

        $("#TextBox1").focusout(function () {
            var txtval = $(this).val();
            if (txtval == "") {
                $(this).attr("placeholder", "please input any words");
            }
        });
    })
```

source : https://forums.asp.net/t/2065367.aspx?Microsoft+Edge+center+align+input+cursor+on+focus

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a modified version of the code from @DMCISSOKHO. This checks for Microsoft Edge and then only attaches to all inputs with a placeholder. It also uses the placeholder when it focusout is called. I am sure it could be modified to not use jQuery, however that is not a requirement for me.

```js
// Bug fix for Microsoft Edge. Inputs with Placeholders and text-aligns other than left.
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge\/(.*)\./)) {
  $(function() {
    $("input[placeholder]").focusin(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.css("text-align").toLowerCase() != "left") {
        $this.attr("data-placeholder", $this.attr("placeholder"));
        $this.attr("placeholder", "");
      }
    }).focusout(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        tempPlaceholder = $this.attr("data-placeholder");
      if (tempPlaceholder != "") {
        $this.attr("placeholder", tempPlaceholder);
        $this.attr("data-placeholder", "");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="This is an example" style="text-align: right" />
```